# Binding data from SQLite to ListView in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8.1, sqlite-net

First I've tried other samples answered here on stackoverflow and tried other examples too but did not find success in my case.

I'm trying to bind data from a table in DB to listview
ListView itself looks like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="lbItems" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Opacity="100" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="White" Background="Transparent">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="cbx" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Content}" Height="58" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" />
            <AppBarButton Tag="{Binding Id}" Grid.Column="1" Icon="Delete" Height="58" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="60" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,0" Click="DeleteButton_Click" />
        </Grid>
    </ListView>
```

and then in C# code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    ObservableCollection<tbl_Items> DB_ItemsList = new ObservableCollection<tbl_Items>();

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        ReadAllItemsList dbitems = new ReadAllItemsList();
        DB_ItemsList = dbitems.GetAllItems();
        lbItems.ItemsSource = DB_ItemsList.OrderBy(i => i.Id).ToList();
    }
```

Here I am following this example for creating the database and database operations: [LINK](http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/windowsphone-81-sqlite-how-to-store.html)

As a result in my listview I am getting only my table name (instead of binding the content from that table).
I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the template code of Listview inside DataTemplate of ListView like this.

```
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="cbx" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Content}" Height="58" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" />
                    <AppBarButton Tag="{Binding Id}" Grid.Column="1" Icon="Delete" Height="58" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="60" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,0" Click="DeleteButton_Click" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you dude, you're life saver. I've spent about a week on this and couldn't find any explanation how to do it.